# Failed to connect to VPN

Tags: openvpn

I am very new in establishing a VPN. I am trying to make a VPN network using my RaspberryPi2 (which has Ubuntu). I am following this ['step by step' guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04). I face some issues in the fourth part, when I have to configure my .ovpn file.
What I do is to open the file with a text editor and I edit the:

```
remote my-server-1 1194
```

based on the IP that my raspberrypi has. In order to get the IP I connect to it via ssh and I use the command:

```
ifconfig.
```

So my .ovpn file looks like:

```
remote my_ip_of_the_raspberry_pi 1194
```

Then I connect my computer to a different LAN network than the raspberrypi is connected and I use Tunnelblick software to access my VPN. But it doesn't work.
I get a message: Waiting for server response.